# Data entered into form not saved

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a script that can generate insurance quotes for multiple postal codes from [this site](https://partner.insurancehotline.com/Quote/Auto?postalCode=K0A1B0&utm_source=Ratelab&utm_medium=Traffic-Partner&utm_campaign=Auto#Vehicles). So far I've managed to enter data into the dialog. Manually entering consists of: clicking the postal code field, a dialog opens, enter postal code and click "continue".

My script looks like this, so far:

```
document.querySelector('.btn.btn-default.postal-code').click();
window.setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("PostalCode").value = "K0A1B0";
}, 2000);
window.setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('.btn.btn-orange.validate-postal-code').click();
}, 2000);
```

If I execute the first two lines, the dialog opens and the postal code gets entered correctly.

If I execute all of it, the postal code doesn't seem to change, but the dialog closes. However, the value is not saved in the field on the main page. What am I doing wrong?

I've done some searching around and tried submitting the form before closing, but don't really know what I need to do here. Neither of these worked:

```
document.forms[0].submit();
document.getElementById("PostalCode").submit();
```

Comment: if both timeout code runs separately and works then you should add more timeout then previous because probably both my run on same time and that generates a conflict.

Comment: are you trying to update the page without refreshing it or after you submit it to another page? without refreshing use document.getelementbyid('somefield').innerhtml= inpute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `setTimeout`, it schedules the execution at the time you specify and then continues executing the next line. In your case, the code in the two `setTimeout` lines will be executed almost at the same time after 2 seconds. You can use 4 second for the second one:

```
document.querySelector('.btn.btn-default.postal-code').click();
window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("PostalCode").value = "K0A1B0";
}, 2000);
window.setTimeout(function(){
     document.querySelector('.btn.btn-orange.validate-postal-code').click();
}, 4000);
```

Alternatively, you can call the second one inside the first one, in which case the first one will be executed after 2 seconds and will schedule the second one to be executed after 2 more seconds:

```
document.querySelector('.btn.btn-default.postal-code').click();
window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("PostalCode").value = "K0A1B0";
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector('.btn.btn-orange.validate-postal-code').click();
    }, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

**EDIT** The value is validated and copied to the main page when the keyboard events are triggered. You can simulate that in JavaScript, but it is easier to do it in jQuery since the website uses it. Add `trigger("change")` after you change the value and you will see the postal code validated and copied to the box on the main page:

```
document.querySelector('.btn.btn-default.postal-code').click();
window.setTimeout(function() {
  $("#PostalCode").val("K1A1B0").trigger("change");
}, 2000);
window.setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('.btn.btn-orange.validate-postal-code').click();
}, 4000);
```

Note: if you use an invalid postal code in the code above, the value will change and get copied, but you will see the validation message and the popup will stay open. If you want to manually validate the postal code, call the `ValidatePostalCode()` function. It returns `true` or `false`, and based on that you can decide what to do next.

Comment: Just so I get it right: You're saying, that both lines get executed at the same time, so I just don't see the change I see, when executing the first two lines only?

I've tried 2 and 4 seconds and it gets changed correctly in the form, but the value still isn't retained.

Comment: The code I run from DevTools in Chrome is basically what I posted before, but with a different value for the second timeout.
`document.querySelector('.btn.btn-default.postal-code').click();
window.setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("PostalCode").value = "K0A1K0";}, 2000);
window.setTimeout(function(){document.querySelector('.btn.btn-orange.validate-postal-code').click();}, 3000);`

I also ran your script and again it doesn't stick.

Comment: I see what you mean. That's because the value is validated and transferred to the main page when the keyboard events are triggered. Entering the value with JavaScript like you're doing doesn't trigger the keyboard events.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Didn't you say it worked for you before? Is there a different approach that enters the data with javascript so that its accepted by the form? I guess they don't want anyone extracting data from their website like this...

Comment: By the way, why don't you contact them to see if they have an API that you can use? They will probably pay you commission for the customers you bring in. Anyway, see the edit in my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comprehensive answer, I really appreciate it.
I will contact them about my plans for sure.

Answer (score 0):

#### MAYBE...

This may be occurring cause you're setting the value,

> window.setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("PostalCode").value = "K0A1B0";}, 2000);

and also submitting it at the same instant... and that's the problem.

> window.setTimeout(function(){document.querySelector('.btn.btn-orange.validate-postal-code').click();}, 2000);

## **Try this out...**

```
var execute = function () {
  'use-strict';
   document.querySelector('.btn.btn-default.postal-code').click();
   window.setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("PostalCode").value = "K0A1B0";}, 2000);
   window.setTimeout(function(){document.querySelector('.btn.btn-orange.validate-postal-code').click();}, 3000);
}();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I wrote under Racil's post, this still doesn't change the value after the dialog opens.
I've tried running your script and it was the same result.